# Angular 15 + SortableJS + Swiper - navigation stops to work

Tags: angular, navigation, swiper.js, sortablejs

I am working on a project where I use cards on a page. These cards are slidable and sortable between each other (Angular 15 + SortableJS + Swiper). After opening the page everything works fine, but when I move (drag and drop) one card (using SortableJS) the card navigation (Swiper) stops working (only navigation - blue arrows on sides).
I do not know if this is a bug or if I can improve it to be working even after dragging?

[I prepared one exact demo, which is stripped just to the basics and shows the problem - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-23dbhf?file=app/app.component.html](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-23dbhf?file=app/app.component.html)

When I was trying to solve the problem, I noticed, that after the drag and drop some part of the "html button" is deleted and therefore the navigation stops working.
I am expecting, that after drag and drop there will be still the working button text.